# Android Room and inheritance. error: Multiple fields have the same columnName

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-room

I have an inheritance relationship that I am trying to persist into a Room database. If I remove the inheritance relationship it works nicely, however if I don't, I get the following error:

```
error: Multiple fields have the same columnName: uuid. Field names: uuid, uuid.
```

This is the base class

```
@Parcelize
open class BaseContent(@PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "uuid") @Expose @SerializedName("uuid") open 
var uuid: String,
@ColumnInfo(name = "category") @Expose @SerializedName("category") 
open var category: String) : Parcelable {

}
```

This is one child class

```
@Entity(tableName = "article")
@Parcelize
data class Article(override var uuid: String,
                    override var category: String,
                    @ColumnInfo(name = "message") @Expose @SerializedName("message") var message: 
String,
                    @ColumnInfo(name = "permanent") @Expose @SerializedName("permanent") var 
permanent: Boolean) : BaseContent(uuid, category) {

}
```

And this is the other child class

```
@Entity(tableName = "post")
@Parcelize
data class Post(override var uuid: String,
                     override var category: String,
                     @ColumnInfo(name = "timestamp") @Expose @SerializedName("timestamp") var 
timeStamp: String,
                     @ColumnInfo(name = "title") @Expose @SerializedName("title") var title: String,
                     @ColumnInfo(name = "description") @Expose @SerializedName("description") var 
description: String) : BaseContent(uuid, category) {

}
```

Any idea of what is going on? If I do it in Java it works just fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemed that you've met with kapt Room's bug (may be not, but I haven't find decent decision)

You can try to choose one of not so elegant alternatives:

1. Instead of parent class use an interface.

`interface BaseContent {
    var uuid: String
    var category: String
}`

2. To throw out inherited fields from your child class (since they will be inherited anyway).

Your base class:

```
@Parcelize
open class BaseContent(
    @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "uuid") @Expose @SerializedName("uuid") open var uuid: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "category") @Expose @SerializedName("category") open var category: String = "") : Parcelable {
}
```

And your child:

```
@Entity(tableName = "article")
@Parcelize
data class Article(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "message") @Expose @SerializedName("message") var message: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "permanent") @Expose @SerializedName("permanent") var permanent: Boolean) : BaseContent() {
}
```

3. Use Java to declare your entities (since you said it works fine).

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using an interface, but to me is only a patch. I still can't understand why that is not working

Comment: If it's a bug, then "that is not working" due to designer's mistake :-) May be there is more correct way, but I haven't found one

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with parcable and inheritance. What I did was that I changed base class and its variables to abstract, which got rid of the error and worked as expected. So:

```
abstract class BaseContent : Parcelable { abstract var baseVar: Int? }
```